# When I run db:migrate it changes my :point database types to :integer in the schema.rb. Why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails app whenever I run "rails db:migrate" it changes existing "point" type fields to "integer" even though it's not part of any migration I defined. My db is a mySQL db. What could be causing this?

Comment: The database dumper (the rails component that converts a sql schema into ruby) might be to blame. You may need to switch to SQL dumps. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because point method does not exist in ActiveRecord.
AR natively supports :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp, :time, :date, :binary, :Boolean.
You could try to use a non-native type using:

```
t.point :point
```